# Differentials for a nonsigular subvarity of a nonsigular variety

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a noetherian regular local ring of dimension $n$, and $P\subset A$ a prime ideal, such that $A/P$ still a regular local ring of dimension $m$.

I want to show $P/P^2$ is a $n-m$ rank free module over $A/P$.

I am reading Hartshorne recently. When I learn "Differentials", I think the answer is yes, but I have a bad command for commutative algebra. I have learned Atiyah before but I can't work it out. Could someone give it a proof or some relative references? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is proven in Tags [00NR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NR), [00NQ](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NQ), and [08KR](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08RK) of the Stacks project.

Comment: Thanks a lot @R.vanDobbendeBruyn